# How to capture multiple repeating patterns with regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I get some string like this: `\input{{whatever}{1}}\mypath{{path1}{path2}{path3}...{pathn}}\shape{{0.2}{0.3}}`
I would like to capture all the paths: path1, path2, ... pathn. I tried the `re` module in python. However, it does not support multiple capture.
For example: `r"\\mypath\{(\{[^\{\}\[\]]*\})*\}"` will only return the last matched group. Applying the pattern to `search(r"\mypath{{path1}{path2}})"` will only return `groups()` as `("{path2}",)`

Then I found an alternative way to do this:

```
    gpathRegexPat=r"(?:\\mypath\{)((\{[^\{\}\[\]]*\})*)(?:\})"
    gpathRegexCp=re.compile(gpathRegexPat)
    strpath=gpathRegexCp.search(r'\mypath{{sadf}{ad}}').groups()[0]
    >>> strpath
    '{sadf}{ad}'
    p=re.compile('\{([^\{\}\[\]]*)\}')
    >>> p.findall(strpath)
    ['sadf', 'ad']
```

or:

```
    >>> gpathRegexPat=r"\\mypath\{(\{[^{}[\]]*\})*\}"
    >>> gpathRegexCp=re.compile(gpathRegexPat, flags=re.I|re.U)
    >>> strpath=gpathRegexCp.search(r'\input{{whatever]{1}}\mypath{{sadf}{ad}}\shape{{0.2}{0.1}}').group()
    >>> strpath
    '\\mypath{{sadf}{ad}}'
    >>> p.findall(strpath)
    ['sadf', 'ad']
```

At this point, I thought, why not just use the findall on the original string? I may use:
`gpathRegexPat=r"(?:\\mypath\{)(?:\{[^\{\}\[\]]*\})*?\{([^\{\}\[\]]*)\}(?:\{[^\{\}\[\]]*\})*?(?:\})"`: if the first `(?:\{[^\{\}\[\]]*\})*?` matches 0 time and the 2nd `(?:\{[^\{\}\[\]]*\})*?` matches 1 time, it will capture `sadf`; if the first `(?:\{[^\{\}\[\]]*\})*?` matches 1 time, the 2nd one matches 0 time, it will capture `ad`. However, it will only return `['sadf']` with this regex.

With out all those extra patterns (`(?:\\mypath\{)` and `(?:\})`), it actually works:

```
    >>> p2=re.compile(r'(?:\{[^\{\}\[\]]*\})*?\{([^\{\}\[\]]*)\}(?:\{[^\{\}\[\]]*\})*?')
    >>> p2.findall(strpath)
    ['sadf', 'ad']
    >>> p2.findall('{adadd}{dfada}{adafadf}')
    ['adadd', 'dfada', 'adafadf']
```

Can anyone explain this behavior to me? Is there any smarter way to achieve the result I want?

Answer (score 2):

```
re.findall("{([^{}]+)}",text)
```

should work

returns

```
['path1', 'path2', 'path3', 'pathn']
```

finally

```
my_path = r"\input{{whatever}{1}}\mypath{{path1}{path2}{path3}...{pathn}}\shape{{0.2}{0.3}}"
#get the \mypath part
my_path2 = [p for p in my_path.split("\\") if p.startswith("mypath")][0]
print re.findall("{([^{}]+)}",my_path2)
```

or even better

```
re.findall("{(path\d+)}",text) #will only return things like path<num> inside {}
```

Comment: To respect Wang's path specification, the regular expression should be `r"\{([^{}[\]]*)\}"`.

Comment: @Joran, thanks for reply, but consider a string buried inside other charaters : `\input{{whatever}{1}}\mypath{{path1}{path2}{path3}...{pathn}}\shape{{0.1}{0.2}}`. It will capture the parameters in `input{}` and `\shape{}` also. It still need to use 2-step capture I guess.

Comment: @ Joran Beasley, Thanks! So it is also 2-step. Can you explain a little bit more why the regex `r"(?:\\mypath\{)(?:\{[^\{\}\[\]]*\})*?\{([^\{\}\[\]]*)\}(?:\{[^\{\}\[\]]*\})*?(?‌​:\})"` can not return all paths with `findall()` either?

Comment: naw with regex you want to keep them short ... long regex's take a long time for me to decode ...

Comment: @Wang: to extract the sequence (step 1): `L = re.findall(r"\\mypath{({.*?})}", input_text)` (assume `\mypath` occurs multiple times). Step 2: for each item in the list `L` call `re.findall("{([^{}]+)}", item)`

Answer (score 1):

You are right. It is not possible to return repeated subgroups inside a group. To do what you want, you can use a regular expression to capture the group and then use a second regular expression to capture the repeated subgroups.

In this case that would be something like: `\\mypath{(?:\{.*?\})}`. This will return `{path1}{path2}{path3}`

Then to find the repeating patterns of `{pathn}` inside that string, you can simply use `\{(.*?)\}`. This will match anything withing the braces. The `.*?` is a non-greedy version of `.*`, meaning it will return the shortest possible match instead of the longest possible match.

Comment: note: [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/0.1.20120904) module supports repeated captures. Though they are not necessary in this case

Comment: @Sebastian. Thanks! This is not a build-in module I guess.

Comment: @Hans Then. Thanks! Can you explain a little bit more why the regex `r"(?:\\mypath\{)(?:\{[^\{\}\[\]]*\})*?\{([^\{\}\[\]]*)\}(?:\{[^\{\}\[\]]*\})*?(?:\})"` can not return all paths with `findall()` either?

Comment: That is because `findall` will return only the patterns that match your regular expression. Since you start with `\mypath`, `findall` will only return matches that start with that string, of which you have only one.